# left and right eigenvectors

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

So far I know every matrix $M$ has left ( $\vec{g}_{k}$ ) and right ( $\vec{e}_{k}$ ) eigenvectors defined via $M \cdot \vec{e}_{k} = \lambda_{k}\vec{e}_{k}$ and $\vec{g}^{t}_{k} \cdot M  = \lambda_{k}\vec{g}^{t}_{k}$ where $\lambda_{k}$ is the corresponding eigenvalue. I know also that $\langle \vec{g}^{t}_{k},\vec{e}_{j} \rangle = 0$ if $\lambda_{k} \neq \lambda_{j}$. However, is it possible that in some cases the scalar product between a left and a right eigenvector is zero even is they correspond to the same eigenvalue which is of multiplicity one?

I would be really grateful if someone can give me an example where this is the case or a proof that this cannot happen.

Comment: Of course $\vec{e}_{k}$ are the right eigenvectors and $\vec{g}_{k}$ are the left ones. I interchanged them in the first sentence. Sorry for that.

Comment: You can edit your question to fix that.

Comment: Sorry that my answer was b**ls**t, sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: This question was answered on MSE [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/827661).